# Права на директорию

Tags: php

Всем привет. У меня такая проблемка не получается поменять права на вновь созданную папку.

```
   $event=mb_substr(sha1(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')), 0,5);
   $directory="img/"."$event"."/";
   $newdirectory=mkdir($directory,0777,true);
   chmod($newdirectory, 0777);
```

> Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in

Но по факту папка создана. Что за проблема может быть?

Comment: удалите последнюю строку `chmod($newdirectory, 0777);` Права на директорию выставляются при её создании.

Comment: а вообще довольно странный у вас подход - вы сохраняете результат mkdir() в переменную $newdirectory, и пытаетесь поменять права для типа boolean -- именно это и будет в переменной, а не директория.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что функция `mkdir` возвращает `boolean`. Результат её выполнения вы записываете в переменную `$newdirectory` и далее вызываете `chmod($newdirectory, 0777);`. Очевидно, что `chmod` требует первым параметром название файла или директории, а не `true` или `false`.
Поскольку название директории у вас лежит в переменной `$directory` то и вызывать `chmod` надо с этой переменной.
`chmod($directory, 0777);`